# Stop trailing slash being added

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router

I'm using `ui-router` and when I click on a link such as `<a ui-sref="signup">Signup</a>` the state gets loaded as normal.

The state looks like this:

```
.state('signup', {
  url: '/signup',
  templateUrl: '/signup/signup.view.html',
  controller: 'signupCtrl'
})
```

However, when I type the address into the address bar, a trailing slash gets added to the url. I realise I could make an extra state to handle this such as:

```
.state('signup2', {
  url: '/signup/',
  templateUrl: '/signup/signup.view.html',
  controller: 'signupCtrl'
})
```

but this is not ideal. Is there a way to stop the slash being added instead? Ideally, it doesn't involve a hack such as this:

```
//remove trailing slash from url so it matches states
$urlRouterProvider.rule(function($injector, $location) {
  var path = $location.path();
  var hasTrailingSlash = path[path.length-1] === '/';

  if(hasTrailingSlash) {

    //if last charcter is a slash, return the same url without the slash  
    var newPath = path.substr(0, path.length - 1); 
    return newPath; 
  }
});
```

as this conflicts with something else I'm using.

**Update**

I'm using:

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
$urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
```

Without html5 mode the problem goes away. So for example, if I type in `/#/signup` then the trailing slash does not get added.

Comment: I'm just curious - why would you need to do this? I've used ui-router several times and even when there is the trailing slash (although it isn't mentioned in the url), it correctly points to the state.

Comment: But it doesn't point to the state.

Comment: For some reason if I type in `mydomain.com/signup` it will add a trailing slash and I'm not sure why?

Comment: My bad, I always thought there was no problem with it but I must have not really checked the path with slash at the end. Now I checked it and it really does matter. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: When you type in a path does a trailing slash get added automatically? Not sure if it's just my app.

Comment: Actually, it doesn't. I've checked that in Firefox and Chrome and it wasn't added at the end after entering the address. However, I've found a workaround to the problem - you can have a look at my answer and check if it works for you.

Comment: Can you reproduce the problem in jsfiddle/plunker?

Comment: How can I do that? I wouldn't be able to type the url

Comment: In plunker there is a popup view. See description on top of the [preview here](http://plnkr.co/edit/iPUvob6frwPBsEHZRXow?p=preview)

Comment: I dont' think the popup view allows you to type the address - only view it

Comment: when you start typing do you see browser hints below the address bar?

Comment: No it's not an autofill issue

Answer (score 1):

I think I've found the solution for the problem. Inject `$urlMatcherFactoryProvider` to the config of the application and set:

`$urlMatcherFactoryProvider.strictMode(false);`

Comment: Thanks. I had actually seen this in the docs. I would prefer to understand why a trailing slash is being added rather than fixing it like this. Looking at your comment in the question section you say doesn't happen in your app, so why is a slash being added to mine I wonder?

Comment: That's a good question. What browser do you use? Does it happen in every browser? If yes, could you provide the whole code of you app configuration?

Comment: It happens in all browsers.